# SLD filter -it is possible to write a unique filter that would filter values ​that contains substering “NEW”

Tags: geoserver, sld

is it possible to make a filter where I define a < Literal > as part of a < PropertyName > ?

For example:

I want do define rule for all valuse in atribute "NOTE" which contains substing "NEW"

this is part example of code for few filters:

```
   <Filter>
    <PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <PropertyName>NOTE</PropertyName>
      <Literal>NEW:2011</Literal>
    </PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </Filter>

   <Filter>
    <PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <PropertyName>NOTE</PropertyName>
      <Literal>NEW:2012</Literal>
    </PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </Filter>

<Filter>
    <PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <PropertyName>NOTE</PropertyName>
      <Literal>NEW:2013</Literal>
    </PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </Filter>
```

it is possible to write a unique filter that would filter values ​​that contain "NEW"

I found that is workin with java regex,and I tried :

```
       <Filter>
        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <PropertyName>NOTE</PropertyName>
          <Literal>{NEW}+</Literal>
        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </Filter>
```

but its not working

additional question and a little bit more complexed:

if I have attribute values : NEW_CAR, OLD_BIKE, OLD_BUS, BUS, NEW_CAT, NEW_DOG, BUS 26,... And I want values which doesnt have substring BUS AND CAT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [`PropertyIsLike` filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#comparison-operators) rather than a [`PropertyIsEqualsTo` filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#comparison-operators) - this would allow you to write a filter like:

```
  <Filter>
    <PropertyIsLike wildCard='%'>
      <PropertyName>NOTE</PropertyName>
      <Literal>NEW%</Literal>
    </PropertyIsLike>
  </Filter>
```

`PropertyIsLike` can only handle basic regexp with simple wildcards, single wildcard and escape characters. If you need a more expressive pattern then you could use the [`isLike` function](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#comparison-functions) which takes a full [Java regexp pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
  <Filter>
    <PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <Function name="isLike">
        <PropertyName>NOTE</PropertyName>
        <Literal>^NEW:\\d+</Literal>
      </Function>
    </PropertyIsEqualTo>
  </Filter>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: see the [Java manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for examples of how to build more complex regexps